# Umbraco Installation with IIS 8.0

Tags: iis, umbraco, iis-8

I'm using Web Platform Installer to install Umbraco 4.11 and I'm wanting to use IIS 8.0 with windows 8.  I did the basic install and everything went smoothly, but when I open the website it redirects me in a loop until I get a 404.15 error.  Query string too long.  Not quite for sure what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the permissions in IIS?

I'd always recommend manually installing Umbraco rather than using the WPI - it's easier and quicker in my opinion